# fopen multiple files to send mail with mail() php

Tags: php, email, send

i have problems to send mail with multiple files with mail() php. Until now, only send the first file, so i need your help please. Give you my code:

HTML:

```
<form action="colabora.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[...]

```
<div id="adjuntos">
<input type="file" name="archivos[]" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

[...]

PHP:

[...]

```
if (isset ($_FILES["archivos"])) {
  $tot = count($_FILES["archivos"]["name"]);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $tot; $i++){
    $_name=$_FILES["archivos"]["name"][$i];
    $_type=$_FILES["archivos"]["type"][$i];
    $_size=$_FILES["archivos"]["size"][$i];
    $_temp=$_FILES["archivos"]["tmp_name"][$i]; 

    //FILES EXISTS
    if(strcmp($_name, "")){
      $fp = fopen($_temp, "rb");
      $file = fread($fp, $_size);
      $file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file)); 
    }

    // FILES HEADERS 
    $headers .= "Content-Type:application/octet-stream ";
    $headers .= "name=\"".$_name."\"r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
    $headers .= "filename=\"".$_name."\"\r\n\n";
    $headers .= "".$file."\r\n";
    $headers .= "--".$num."--";
  }
}
```

[...]

mail($para, $asunto, $body, $headers)

Comment: my code get all the content , the problem is that not all files sent by email, only the first.

Comment: I have already done and get all files. I think the problem is $file must be an array to open and read all files. Can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noted you have lost a boundary before each attachment.

```
// FILES HEADERS 
$headers .= "--".$num."\r\n";  // Boundary
$headers .= "Content-Type:application/octet-stream ";
$headers .= "name=\"".$_name."\"r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
$headers .= "filename=\"".$_name."\"\r\n\n";
$headers .= $file."\r\n";
```

The closing boundary (ended with "--") should be placed outside the loop:

```
$headers .= "--".$num."--\r\n";
```

Comment: What is the `$tot` value after `$tot = count(...)` ? Also you can make `print_r($_FILES["archivos"]);` to see its contents after submit.

Comment: $tot = 5, and i dont have attached 5 files.

Comment: I've replaced my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is something here that causes it. Show contents of $body right after files:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type:application/octet-stream ";
$headers .= "name=\"".$_name."\"r\n";       
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
$headers .= "filename=\"".$_name."\"\r\n\n";
$headers .= "".$file."\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."\r\n";
```